# How to pause all jQuery functions and DOM loading during function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using jQuery scrollTo() for smooth scrolling on my site. Works excellent except during the initial loading. While the images on the page are loaded, it makes the smooth scroll not so smooth and it's pretty laggy. What's worse, I'm also pre-loading all other images from the rest of the site so it takes even longer (although hidden) to load everything.

So the question is can you stop all processing during scrollTo() that will pause all loading, smooth scroll the page, then go back to loading?

The jQuery I'm using for scrollTo:

```
$('.smooth-scroll').click(function(e){
            var dest = $(this).attr("href");
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(dest).offset().top -60
            }, 1000);
        });
```

And for the image preload:

```
image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "images/image.jpg"
```

If it's possible to pause all this, what do I need to add here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent image loading like that :

```
var unloaded = [];
$('img.noload').each(function (image) {
    unloaded.push(image);
    image._src = image.src;
    image.src = 'loader.gif'; // Use an loading image to prevent "ALT" attribute effect
});
```

After your scroll is completed (callback function), call and apply real SRC to your different image:

```
unloaded.each(function (image) {
    image.src = image._src;
});
```

Make sure to disabled just content image (text illustration) because this solution can prevent your design image loading.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all of Your jquery code into $(window).load binding, that will set handlers after everything is loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.smooth-scroll').click(function(e){
            var dest = $(this).attr("href");
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(dest).offset().top -60
            }, 1000);
        });

});
```

or write code as in **Thibault Bach**'s answer.

Comment: Right, but in case your images are so weighty to load your scroll will be execute to later.

Answer (score 0):

set width and height to  with CSS or HTML `<img src="img.jpg" height="200" width="100" />`

Comment: Correct, but if you use an responsive design, your width and heigth can be dynamic. Secondly is to hard to set all of image dimension , above all if your text contain lot of images.

Comment: you need to mentain these class in other style sheets as well with different  width and height.

Comment: If content is insert and contain in database (ex: blog site) , how could you change that without edit manualy your CSS? I think isn't it a usefull solution and so hard to maintain.

Comment: Correct, this solution might not fit for all cases. This is one of the ways to fix the above issue.